# Can you use Bind("field") for DataLists for updating

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to use a datalist as it offers more flexibility to design the selected row and edit. (Fields over two rows)

In Gridviews, it is possible to use Bind("field") and automatically pass parameters back to the SqlDatasouce on the update event.

However, this doesn't seem to work for DataLists, values are passed back as NULLS.

I can see a Microsoft article showing use of Eval() and then using Item.FindControl in code behind to map the parameters:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90xwe9s3(v=vs.100).aspx

This seems messy, is there a reason why I can't just Bind in the EditItemTemplate ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the DataList was extended to work with the ASP.NET 2.0 data source controls, I guess it's something to do DataLists do not have all of the extensibility points or features of the official ASP.NET 2.0 data Web controls enjoyed by the GridView, DetailsView, and FormView